# LWC Navigation Mixin not replacing current page?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

When i try to navigate to a webpage it's loading in a new page. I want to replace current page url with the navigation URL. It' not working with below code. can anyone tell how to replace current page????

```
<template>
    <button onclick={navigateToWebPage}>Click To Navigate</button>
</template>

import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
export default class SelectComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
navigateToWebPage() {
    // Navigate to a URL
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: 'http://salesforce.com'
        }
    },
    true // Replaces the current page in your browser history with the URL
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Navigate to WebPage
navigateToWebPage() {
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: ''
        }
    }).then(url => {
        window.open("http://salesforce.com", "_self");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like below,

parentLWCComponent.html

Template

```
<template>
        <lightning-card >
            <lightning-button label="The Parent LWC" onclick={navigateToChildLWC}></lightning-button>
        </lightning-card><br/>
</template>
```

parentLWCComponent.js file

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class ParentPage extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    navigateToChildLWC() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        "type": "standard__component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__AuraComponent"    
        }
    });
}
```

Create an aura component as below to call the child LWC component from the Parent LWC component.

AuraComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component  implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >
   <c:childLWCComponent/>
</aura:component>
```

Crete your child LWC component,

childLWCComponent.html

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello World! </h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with NavigationMixin not replacing the current page with the navigation URL. I used JS as a workaround here, see below, it is working for me.

window.location.replace("https://www.google.com/");